# After user login navigate to HTML file in root directory of asp.net core web and update current page URL in address bar with logout button

Tags: iframe

Using an asp.net core web app that serves static (HTML) files located in the root directory (outside the www root folder) of the aps.net core web app with any authentication (Azure ad or adb2c). Once the user is logged in the logout button should be displayed with a static (HTML) file on the web page that updates the address bar of the current page.

Considering that we have Html files in root directory of asp.net core web app, we need to display those user once logged in with logout button and current page address bar.

I placed some HTML files in the root directory (outside of www root folder) of aps.net core web app to provide azure ad authentication to asp.net core web app.
After user login it will redirect to index.html file here, but I want to display logout button along with it and without changing HTML file because html files I will change sometimes or remove, etc...  so, here concept like we have display logout button and html file which are in root directory with updating URL of current web page. how do we achieve this?

I tried with Iframe tag but in this scenario, we can't update URL because it works like web page in web page.

Is there any way to achieve this?